# Silverstripe - cms fields not saving to database

Tags: php, database, silverstripe

Since moving site to a new server form fields under configuration tab are no longer saving to database. Running same config as old server, SilverStripe 2.3.3 and PHP 5.2.17. Can't see any log or php errors being thrown.

Other fields are saving okay so the problem is specific to this set of fields.

I assume this is the code responsible for the function. Can anyone see any obvious reason this isn't working??

```
<?php

class Product extends Page {

public static $db = array(
    'ProductIntro' => 'Text',
    'ProductPrice' => 'Text',  
    'SpecialOffer' => 'Boolean',
    'HidePrice' => 'Boolean',
    'OneMonthPrice' => 'Currency',
    'ThreeMonthPrice' => 'Currency',
    'FourMonthPrice' => 'Currency',
    'SixMonthPrice' => 'Currency',
    'OutrightPrice' => 'Currency',
    'DeliveryPrice' => 'Currency',
    'DefaultPrice' => 'Enum("OneMonthPrice,ThreeMonthPrice,FourMonthPrice,SixMonthPrice","OneMonthPrice")',
    'VideoEmbedCode' => 'HTMLText'
);

public static $has_one = array(
    'ProductImage' => 'EnhancedImage'
);

public static $has_many = array(
    'ProductGalleryImages' => 'ProductGalleryImage',
    'ProductDownloads' => 'ProductDownload'
);

public static $many_many = array(
    'RelatedProducts' => 'Product'                               
);

static $belongs_many_many = array(
    'IsRelatedProduct' => 'Product'
);


static $allowed_children = array( );


public function getNextSibling() {

    return DataObject::get("Product", "ParentID = $this->ParentID && Sort > $this->Sort && Status = 'Published'", "Sort ASC", null, 1);
}

public function getPreviousSibling() {
    return DataObject::get("Product", "ParentID = $this->ParentID && Sort < $this->Sort && Status = 'Published'", "Sort DESC", null, 1);
}


public function SiblingProducts() {
     if ($this->getField("ParentID")) {

        return DataObject::get("Product", "ParentID = " . $this->getField("ParentID").' AND `SiteTree_Live`.ID != '.$this->getField("ID"));
    } else return false;
}

public function SubCategory() {
    if ($this->getField("ParentID")) {
        return DataObject::get_one("ProductSubCategory", "`SiteTree_Live`.ID = " . $this->getField("ParentID"));
    } else return false;
}

public function HasSubCategory() {
    if ($this->SubCategory()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function Category() {
    if ($this->HasSubCategory()) {
        $parent_id = $this->SubCategory()->getField("ParentID");
    } else {
        $parent_id = $this->getField("ParentID");
    }
    if ($parent_id) {
        return DataObject::get("ProductCategory", "`SiteTree_Live`.ID = " . $parent_id);
    } else return false;
}

public function IsFeaturedProduct() {
    $hp = DataObject::get_one("ProductHomepage");
    if ($hp) {
        if ($hp->FeaturedProduct()) {
            if ($hp->FeaturedProduct()->getField('ID') && $hp->FeaturedProduct()->getField('ID') == $this->getField('ID')) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function IsCategorySpecial() {

    if( $this->parent()->CategoryFeaturedProductID == $this->ID ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


function onAfterWrite() {  
if (isset($_POST['AddedViaObjectManager']) && $_POST['SetPageToLive'] && $this->stagesDiffer('Stage','Live')) {
    $this->Status = 'Published';
    $this->Publish('Stage', 'Live');
}
parent::onAfterWrite();
}

function getCMSFields_forPopup() {
  $fields = new FieldSet();
  $fields->push( new TextField( 'Title', 'Product Title' ) );
  $fields->push( new TextField( 'ProductIntro', 'Product Intro' ) );
  $fields->push( new TextField( 'ProductPrice', 'Price ($)' ) );
  $fields->push( new CheckboxField( 'SpecialOffer', 'This Product is a Special Offer' ) );
  $record = DataObject::get('ProductSubCategory', "");
  if ($record) {
      $map = $record->toDropDownMap('ID', 'Title');
  } else {
      $map = array();
  }
  $fields->push( new DropdownField('ParentID','Sub Category',$map) );
  $fields->push( new SimpleHTMLEditorField( 'Content', 'Content' ));
  $fields->push( new DropdownField('SetPageToLive','After Update, Set Product Page To:',array('1'=>'Live','0'=>'Draft')) );
  $fields->push( new FileIFrameField('ProductImage') );
  $fields->push( new HiddenField('AddedViaObjectManager','AddedViaObjectManager',1) );
  return $fields;
}

function getCMSFields() {
  $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

  $product = new VerticalTabSet(
        new VerticalTab('Configuration',array(
            new LiteralField("ConfDescription","<br /><em>Product pages support a range of additional features such as pricing.</em><br /><br />"),
            new TextField('ProductIntro', 'Intro Text'),
            new TextField('ProductPrice', 'From Text (Formerly Price)'),
            new CheckboxField("HidePrice","Hide Price"),
            new CheckboxField("SpecialOffer","This Product is currently on special."),
            new LiteralField("ldiv","<br /><br /><h2>Pricing</h2>"),
            new CurrencyField("OneMonthPrice", "One Month Hire Price"),
            new CurrencyField("ThreeMonthPrice", "Three Month Hire Price"),
            new CurrencyField("FourMonthPrice", "Four Month Hire Price"),
            new CurrencyField("SixMonthPrice", "Six Month Hire Price"),
            new CurrencyField("OutrightPrice", "Outright Purchase Price"),
            new CurrencyField("DeliveryPrice", "Delivery Price"),
            new DropDownField("DefaultPrice", "Selected Pricing Option", array('OneMonthPrice'=>'1 Month','ThreeMonthPrice'=>'3 Month','FourMonthPrice'=>'4 Month','SixMonthPrice'=>'6 Month'))
        )),
        new VerticalTab('RelatedProducts',array(
            new LiteralField("RelatedDescription","<br /><em>Related products are displayed on a product page to direct users to other options.</em><br /><br />"),
            new ManyManyDataObjectManager(
                $this, // Controller
                'RelatedProducts', // Source name
                'Product', // Source class
                array(
                    'Title' => 'Title'
                ), // Headings
                'getCMSFields_forPopup' // Detail fields (function name or FieldSet object)
            )
        )),
        new VerticalTab('Images',array(
            new LiteralField("ImageryDescription","<br /><em>The Main Image is used as the default image for this product.</em><br /><br />"),
            new FileIFrameField('ProductImage', 'Main Image'),
            new LiteralField ("ProdImages",'<br /><h4 style="margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">Upload Product Images</h4><br /><em>Supports all image types, however web images are recommended.</em><br /><br />'),
            new ImageDataObjectManager(
                $this, // Controller
                'ProductGalleryImages', // Source name
                'ProductGalleryImage', // Source class
                'Image', // File name on DataObject
                array(
                    'Title' => 'Title'
                ), // Headings
                'getCMSFields_forPopup' // Detail fields (function name or FieldSet object)
            )
        )),
        new VerticalTab('Downloads',array(
            new LiteralField("ImageryDescription","<br /><em>Add files users can download.</em><br /><br />"),
            new FileDataObjectManager(
                $this, // Controller
                'ProductDownloads', // Source name
                'ProductDownload', // Source class
                'File', // File name on DataObject
                array(
                    'Title' => 'Title'
                ), // Headings
                'getCMSFields_forPopup' // Detail fields (function name or FieldSet object)
            )
        )),
        new VerticalTab('Video',array(
            new LiteralField("VideoDescription","<br /><em>Add the embed code here.</em><br /><br />"),
            new TextareaField('VideoEmbedCode', 'Video Embed Code', 4)
        ))
  );

  $product->setOpenTab('Configuration');

  //$fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Content.Product",$product);

  $fields->insertAfter(new Tab('Configuration',$product),'Main');



  //$fields->insertAfter(new Tab('Related Products',$product_rel),'Main');



  //$main = $fields->fieldByName('Main');

  //$main->title = 'Product Details';


  return $fields;
}

 function HirePrices() {
   $prices = new DataObjectSet();

   $keys = array(
     'OneMonthPrice' => 'One Month',
     'ThreeMonthPrice' => 'Three Month',
     'FourMonthPrice' => 'Four Month',
     'SixMonthPrice' => 'Six Month',
   );
   $f = true;
   foreach($keys as $price_item => $title) {
       if ($this->$price_item > 0) {
           $p = $this->$price_item;
           $prices->push(new ArrayData( array(
                'price' => $p,
                'nice_price' => '$'.number_format($p,2),
                'title' => $title,
                'First' => $f,
                'IsDefault' => ($this->DefaultPrice == $price_item) ? true : false
            )));
           $f = false;
       }
   }

   return ($prices) ? $prices : false;

}

}

class Product_Controller extends Page_Controller {

public function init() {
    parent::init();

}

function Category() {
    return $this->data()->Category();
}

function SiblingProducts() {
    return $this->data()->SiblingProducts();
}



}

?>
```

Comment: if this is a page the I would assume there is a getCMSFields function that would be key to giving any help here.  Else could you clarify if you are using some other edit form - e.g. ModelAdmin.

Comment: what happens when you run `/dev/build?flush=all`?

Comment: Silverstripe 3.x needs at least PHP 5.3 to run. PHP 5.2 is totally outdated, you should update your server to latest php 5.6, which runs also much faster than old 5.2

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Site is running Silverstripe 2 which I'm told requires PHP 5.2 which is outdated yes but easier to maintain the current config that was working on previous server. This is only temporary while I work on developing a new site.

Comment: Dev/rebuild didn't have any affect. Even tried creating a new database but still no change to the issue

Comment: @kegs: i guess i misread your original question. Sorry for bothering. I guess you should enable error logging and look at the logs if any errors occur when running dev/build or save. Or use xdebug to analyse the save process...

Answer (score 3):

From Silverstripe 3.1 on the `$db` and other definitions must be declared as `private static` variables, so they can be cached (and overwritten) by the config system.

```
<?php

class Product extends Page {

private static $db = array(
...
);
```

There is also a [module that upgrades your code for you](https://github.com/sunnysideup/silverstripe-upgrade_silverstripe) and does 90% of the work for getting old 2.4 code running on 3.x.

Answer (score 3):

While it is sound advice to encourage people to upgrade, the OP seems to have their reasons for not so-doing at this time.

If the server config and PHP version are the same, OK - but what about the database? You don't mention what RDBMS and version you were using on the old host, and what you're using on the new.

First thing's first - are there *really* no server errors logged? In your new setup, does your php.ini file match the one from the legacy server? Is this problem only in dev or prod? In your dev env, I strongly suggest you set `error_reporting` to be `E_ALL` and `dislay_errors` to `on`. Check the location where php.ini says it is logging errors. This can be the server's syslog, apache log or a dedicated php_errors logfile. Ensure each of these files is read+writeable otherwise nothing will be logged.

Looking down your data model I can see some calls to `DataObject::get()` with some raw SQL inserted as an SQL `WHERE` clause. This is OK, but some seem to be inconsistently escaped (at least they differ from how you've escaped other such clauses) e.g. `getPreviousSibling()` and `getNextSibling()`. Is it possible your RDBMS (MySQL, Postgres etc) are a different version with differing expectations as to how incoming queries should be constructed and escaped?

Have you checked the query-log for your RDBMS? What does it say?